# Text Transformation in a File with SED

Tags: regex, macos, sed

Given the csv file called *address.txt*:

```
Buddy,Guy,49085
Otis,Rush,60194
```

How can I convert the file to just contain the zip code?
My commandline test is not working and I am not sure why.
I am getting the untransformed text returned from `cat`

```
cat address.txt | sed  's/\(.+\),\(.+\),\(.+\)/\3/g'
```

Comment: Thanks but did not work. I figured it out below.

Comment: Have you considered using a tool specifically for handling CSV files, like csvkit? https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/749/

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
cat address.txt | sed  's/[^,]*,[^,]*,\([^,]*\)/\1/'
```

It's easier in sed to describe what the pattern should not contain VS. what it should, at least for this problem

Answer (score 0):

This does it (using GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.+,(.+)/\1/' address.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*,//' address.txt
```

or

```
awk -F, '{print $NF}' address.txt
```